# Bash missing ']' error for output

Tags: escaping, bash

I wrote a function that is in my `~/.bashrc` file to clean configuration files of comments. The function is as follows:

```
clean_config()
{
    [ -z "$2"] && CLEANCHAR="#" || CLEANCHAR="$2"
    egrep -v "^[[:space:]]*${CLEANCHAR}|^$" "$1" | uniq
}
```

Basically it states if the user doesn't pass a 2nd argument, use `#` as the comment character to look for and clean. The first argument is just the file itself. The function "works" but when I run it with `;` as the character to clean, I get the following:

```
[root@server]: /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d # clean_config www.conf \;
bash: [: missing `]'
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

It escapes the character fine, but I always get that `bash: [: missing ']'` line at the top. I've tried changing it to `[[ -z "$2"]]` but that causes bash.bashrc to not load at all.

Any ideas? Version info below:

```
[root@server]: ~ # bash --version | head -n1
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: choroba's answer is correct, but note that you could simplify the code by using `CLEANCHAR=${2-#}`.  Note also that the function will not work correctly if you specify a CLEANCHAR that is a regular expression metacharacter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space before the closing `]` is not optional:

```
[ -z "$2" ]
#        ^
```

Without it, the command is OK only when `$2` is empty, so it becomes `[ -z ]`.

The same applies to `[[ ... ]]`, but you don't have to quote the variables inside:

```
[[ -z $2 ]]
```

Comment: @ScottCrooks: They are different. `[[` don't need quoting, support logical operators `&&` and `||`, but are not supported in other shell types.

Answer (score 2):

There are [bash parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to provide this kind of "default value" assignments:

```
$ set -- x "second arg"
$ CLEANCHAR=${2:-#}
$ echo "$CLEANCHAR"
second arg

$ set -- x
$ CLEANCHAR=${2:-#}
$ echo "$CLEANCHAR"
#

$ set -- x ""
$ CLEANCHAR=${2:-#}
$ echo "$CLEANCHAR"
#
```

`${x:-default}` means: if `$x` is unset or empty, use the "default" value